# Convert html table row span to CSS

Tags: html, css

I checked some of the posts here regarding conversion from html table to css but can't find what I am looking and hoping for some help.

I am using a table as a graphical presentation of some lockers that have different sizes. As a result, some table cells span multiple rows. All was fine when there were a few static models. Now I have to deal with dynamic configurations and tables are just a pain, so I am trying to convert it to CSS.

I am running into some problems when cell spans multiple rows and not sure how to set up the CSS. I need to see how it is done statically before attempting to generate the code dynamically.

Here is a short sample:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td7" rowspan="4" height="100">R0C0</td>
        <td id="Td8" height="25" >R0C1</td>
        <td id="Td9" height="25" >R0C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td10" height="25" >R1C1</td>
        <td id="Td11" height="25" >R1C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td12" height="25" >R2C1</td>
        <td id="Td13" height="25" >R2C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td14" height="25" >R3C1</td>
        <td id="Td15" height="25" >R3C2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS (Attempt), can get the first row but not sure how to do the rest:

```html
<div>
    <span style="display:inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;border:solid 1px black;vertical-align:top;">R0C0</span>
    <span style="display:inline-block;width:100px;height:25px;border:solid 1px black;vertical-align:top;">R0C1</span>
    <span style="display:inline-block;width:100px;height:25px;border:solid 1px black;vertical-align:top;">R0C2</span>
</div>
```

Also tried css "table", using the code in one of the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962055/convert-html-table-to-just-css):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .css-table {
        display: table;
        background-color:#ccc;
        width: 350px;
    }
.css-table-tr { 
    display: table-row;     
}

.css-table-td_small { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-blok;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.css-table-td_medium { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-blok;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.css-table-td_large { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-blok;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.css-table-td_kiosk { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height:150px;
    display:inline-blok;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
<div class="css-table">
    <div class="css-table-tr">
        <span class="css-table-td_kiosk">R0C0</span>
        <span class="css-table-td_small">R0C1</span>
        <span class="css-table-td_small">R0C2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

This is the (sample) table I need I need to convert. The position and size of lockers will change depending on the model. If I can figure out what one model would look like using CSS, I can work it out to make it dynamic. L, M and S in parenthesis imply locker size. Medium is 2 times small, large is 4 times small and Kiosk is 6 times small locker size.

```
<table border="1" style="width:600px">
    <tr>
        <td id="Td1" height="100" >K01D04 (L)</td>
        <td id="Td2" height="100" >C02D08 (L)</td>
        <td id="Td3" height="100" >C03D08 (L)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td4" height="25" >K01D03 (S)</td>
        <td id="Td5" height="25" >C02D07 (S)</td>
        <td id="Td6" height="25" >C03D07 (S)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td7" rowspan="5" height="150" class="kPL_Kiosk">KIOSK</td>
        <td id="Td8" height="25" >C02D06 (S)</td>
        <td id="Td9" height="25" >C03D06(S)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td10" height="25" >C02D05 (S)</td>
        <td id="Td11" height="25" >C03D05 (S)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td12" height="25" >C02D04 (S)</td>
        <td id="Td13" height="25" >C03D04 (S)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td14" height="25" >C02D03 (S)</td>
        <td id="Td15" height="25" >C03D03 (S)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td16" height="50" >C02D02 (M)</td>
        <td id="Td17" height="50" >C03D02 (M)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td18" height="50" >K01D02 (M)</td>
        <td id="Td19" rowspan="2" height="100" >C02D01 (L)</td>
        <td id="Td20" rowspan="2" height="100" >C03D01 (L)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Td21" height="50">K01D01 (M)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Edit 2:

The image below shows what I need to display (one variation). L: large locker, height 100 px, M: medium, height 50 px; S: small; height 25 px. However, I do not seem to be able to get the lockers to display column-wise even though I specify flex-direction: column.

[image: Locker System Sample]

Edit 3:

This is the CSS and HTML I am using. Once I added width and height to flex-direction, it started to display the images column-wise. I guess this is an undocumented requirement. However, now everything is displayed in column. This is what I have:

```
.lockers {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.locker-column {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height:420px;
    width:100px;
}
img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-flex-grow:1;
    flex-grow:1;
  }

<div class="lockers">
    <div class="locker-column">
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\L.png" title="R1C1-L" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C1-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\Kiosk.png" title="Kiosk" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\M.png" title="R4C1-M" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\M.png" title="R5C1-M" />
    </div>
    <div class="locker-column"> 
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\L.png" title="R1C2-L" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C2-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C3-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C4-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C5-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C6-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\M.png" title="R2C7-M" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\L.png" title="R2C8-L" />
    </div>
    <div class="locker-column">
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\L.png" title="R1C3-L" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R2C3-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R3C3-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R4C3-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R5C3-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\S.png" title="R6C3-S" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\M.png" title="R7C3-M" />
        <img src="..\assets\images\Lockers\L.png" title="R8C3-L" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit 4:

[image]

Comment: There is actually a `display: table` I think if you do some research on that, it would most likely solve your problem

Comment: There is no CSS table row span

Comment: I edited the question to include the display:table I had already tried.

Comment: I know there is no row span in CSS; I was wondering if there is a way to fake it using CSS, or if I am stuck with using tables.

Comment: Dude, you should NEVER use tables. Like EVER. Unless you're coding HTML email templates. That's the only exception.

Comment: Can you use fixed width on the row span?

Comment: I am using 100 pixel widths for all; eventually I have to use images as backgrounds to depict lockers and their status (different locker door color depending on their status: available, occupied, Error, etc.). The problem is that, for example, a kiosk spans 6 small lockers. So when I add a kiosk, I need to add 6 small lockers next to it.

Comment: Then replace the p in my solution with an icon or whatever. It'll still work. Use flex-basis on locker-column if you want a certain column to have a certain width.

Comment: Lets do this, post an image showing the result you need. What @zsawaf suggested might work perfect

Comment: I'll update my answer to show a bunch of random locker images.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the actual table I am trying to convert. Placing images as cell background will be done separately when a locker is selected by the user and its locker status is fetched from database.

Comment: @NoBullMan Checkout the edit. It's worth taking some time and looking into flexboxes. I recommended some tutorials for you to do.

Comment: @zsawaf Table elements are perfectly fine for their intended use and tables should never be used for layout. To say you should never use table is not correct.

Comment: @Rob the only reason you'd need to use tables is for strictly two reasons, 1- creating html email templates. 2- literally displaying a table, like an excel sheet. In the majority of the cases, this is not what people are trying to do. So yes, I say again, you should NEVER use tables for layouts. Ask any experienced front end developer / fullstack developer with experience and knowledge of modern CSS or web design.

Comment: @zsawaf Yes but you didn't say "for layouts". You said to only use them for email. Hence my comment; a 12-year experienced full stack developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use display: table. Is this what you're looking for?

**Edit: *Elaboration***

I don't think you're grasping the concept..

I'll try to explain to you how you should be thinking about this. Usually with tables, you're thinking in terms of rows, where that might be the case with flexboxes, when I wrote my solution I was thinking about it in terms of columns.

Notice how I have flex-direction: column on the children of lockers? This div literally spans the entire column, from top to bottom. You can do whatever you want, put whatever lockers you want, of whatever size.

If you have absolutely no experience with flexboxes I recommend you read up on it, but the solution below gives you a core foundation to what you are trying to do.

[This tutorial](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) is a good starting point.

```css
.lockers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.locker-column {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100px;
}
.locker {  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 2px 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.large {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.small {
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
}

.medium {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  height: 50px;  
}

.kiosk {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lockers">
  <div class="locker-column">
    <div class="large locker">L11</div>
    <div class="small locker">S21</div>
    <div class="kiosk locker">Kiosk</div>
    <div class="medium locker">M81</div>
    <div class="medium locker">M91</div>
  </div>
  <div class="locker-column">
    <div class="large locker">L12</div>
    <div class="small locker">S22</div>
    <div class="small locker">S32</div>
    <div class="small locker">S42</div>
    <div class="small locker">S52</div>
    <div class="small locker">S62</div>
    <div class="medium locker">M72</div>
    <div class="large locker">M82</div>
  </div>
  <div class="locker-column">
    <div class="large locker">L13</div>
    <div class="small locker">S23</div>
    <div class="small locker">S33</div>
    <div class="small locker">S43</div>
    <div class="small locker">S53</div>
    <div class="small locker">S63</div>
    <div class="medium locker">M73</div>
    <div class="large locker">M83</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This sounds promising since when user selects a particular locker system (potentially different number of lockers and locker size configuration) I will have each column of lockers stored in a separate data table within a data set (data read from database). If this does what I am looking for, I should be able to generate the code, similar to your example, on the fly. I will let you know how it goes once I read up on flexboxes.

Comment: I read up and tried it and it looks good. The only question is that flex-direction column does not seem to display items column-wise (or I am missing something). I added a "title = x" (x=1, 2, 3 ,...) to your images and it seems they are displayed in rows. I tried different variations and I get the same thing.

Comment: I added an image of what I am looking for. I can't get the darn lockers to display column-wise Your example also adds images in a row not column (see previous comment)

Comment: @NoBullMan I'll take a look at this tomorrow and hopefully we'll figure it out ;)

Comment: Thanks. Please take a look at "Edit 3"; I managed to display them in columns by adding "height: xxx" but now everything is in columns (one column).

Comment: @NoBullMan I updated the code to demonstrate what you had posted. Unfortunately, I didn't have much time to play around with it and I explicitly set the height on the kiosk, which isn't very good. The height should be automatically set for the kiosk to cover the remaining space, or at least I assume that's what you want. If you're in a hurry, take the snippet above, and ask how you can apply flex-grow to the kiosk box. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. I copied your updated styles and divs and unfortunately they all show up in one long column. I added a "height:450px" to ".lockers" and ".locker-column"; I don't think they would display in column without height specified. Nonetheless, it displays in columns but just one long one. I appreciate you taking time to assist.

Comment: @NoBullMan If you copy pasted my exact code, then it must be the outer container that wraps the code.. Can you maybe show it to me? Try opening your console and play around with the css properties of the outer container, and see what is breaking it.

Comment: The only thing I changed in your code was adding a "height:450px" to "locker" and "locker-column" styles. I added a screen shot under Edit 4.

Comment: OK, I noticed I had IE 10 on the dev server and thought that might be the issue. I published it (test site) and ran it in IE 11 and got the same result. However, in FF and Chrome it shows correctly as columns and in the right order.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Once I duplicate flex elemnts with -webkit-xxxx, it works in IE 11 as well. I have to tweak some of the alignment probalems I am facing now but no biggy; you halped me with main hurdle.

Comment: @NoBullMan oh yes! You have to be very careful with adding prefixes. I assumed you were working with a modern browser. Glad I helped! Cheers :)